# Android Studio consuming all the system RAM and swap mermory

Tags: linux, android-studio, ubuntu, memory, ram

I have ubuntu20.04LTS installed on my desktop
Android Studio version 4.1.3
Intel Pentium G645 @ 2.90 Ghz dual core
6 GB of RAM
1.5GB of swap
I am learning android but my projects are not that heavy but then too my pc hangs even if I open android studio alone it just starts consuming RAM and swap memory slowly 
What can I do to fix this problem please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit custom VM Options**
Add or change the value of `-Xmx`. Units are MB (specified as `m`) or GB (specified as `g`). Here I tell it to only use 2 GB RAM:

```
-Xmx2g
```

JetBrains totally reworked the user interface recently, in fact the UI is quite fluid between major releases. Android Studio is based on the same core as IntelliJ IDEA, and for the current version you would clock on the settings icon at the lower left of the signon screen, then you will see VM settings.

Comment: I have tried that after two or three builds processes named java stay in background and they not free up the memory